# Unwanted Hyperref link

Tags: hyperref

I'm using the below code in a Tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Author field\thanks{Corresponding author. E-mail: \href{mailto:tenraa@uvt.nl}{tenraa@uvt.nl}}}

\maketitle
\section{INTRODUCTION}\label{sec1}

Climate change presses for environmental policy analysis. The recent economic literature stresses the
importance of technical change for curbing emissions, and
proposes policies that can achieve it.
Efficient allocation of production activities may
aid the realization of international environmental policy
targets, such as stipulated in the Kyoto Protocol
the EU climate and energy package (2009).\footnote{An anonymous referee observed that by
\href{http://ec.europa.eu/clima/policies/package/index_en.htm}{http://ec.europa.eu/clima/policies/package/index\_en.htm}.}

\end{document}
```

After creating the PDF the last word of the paragraph "(2009)" is showing the below link in the PDF. If I remove the `\thanks` command in the author field it is coming correctly.

Could you please advise how to avoid the below link in PDF.

[image]

Comment: Which `hyperref` driver are you using (pdflatex, latex/dvips/ps2pdf, ...)? Have you tried a different PDF viewer?

Comment: @Murthy: I compiles correctly for my, with right mailto-link, using `pdflatex` and latest `hyperref` version